# Nuget in Visual Studio: "entry with same key already exists"

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I ran into an issue with Nuget more recently where suddenly I couldn't add new packages to certain projects. The error Visual Studio threw was `Entry with same key already exists` - after searching and finding [this thread](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1412) I was still coming up blank. I wanted to post a solution that actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to navigate to `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` and open up the `NuGet.config` file.

Under `<packageSources>` I ended up having (unknown how this happened) two entries for Nuget.org:

```
   <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
   <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
```

I opted to keep the bottom of the two as the real one, since [Nuget.org's docs](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings) state this to be a good package source. Removing the first entry or renaming it to something like `<add key="nuget.org2" ... />` resolved the issue. It might be helpful to also note that I performed this fix while Visual Studio remained closed.

Comment: Yeah, no, that doesn't work generally.  There's no duplicate entries in my file and I'm getting the "entry with same key already exists".  I take it because it's the same key it already exists (duh) but what is that a reference to and what's the fix?